# rospy logging not printing across computers

Tags: ros, machines, rospy, print, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**The Setup:** Two computers, both running various nodes. Computer A is the master where the launch file is run from that launched all the nodes being used. Computer B is a slave running several nodes as directed by Computer A.

**The Problem:** While running a python node, I noticed that none of the rospy.log*() calls print anything to the screen on A when it is called by a node on B. However calling the rospy logging functions while on A prints on A (I haven't tried checking B, as I'm not sure how to force ROS terminal output).

**My Attempts:** I've tried all of the logging levels, and manually setting the log level of the node, but no dice. As a workaround I've just been publishing debug information to a topic from the node in B and echoing the topic on A, but this is a messy way to get it done and it would be simpler to just have everything print in the main terminal the launch file is run from.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40797/rospy-logging-not-printing-across-computers/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-07**:
What does `rxconsole` show?

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-08-08**:
I can only ssh into the computers, so I can't use and GUI interfaces.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-08**:
Have you tried `ssh -X`?

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-08-08**:
That did the trick, and rxconsole does seem to receive the messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is expected behavior: from http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Architecture,

"Remote processes do not forward their stderr/stdout to your local console. In general, nodes should be reporting important information using ROS' builtin logging mechanisms (i.e. rosconsole for roscpp, logout/logerr for rospy, etc...). This allows you to view this important information via the rosout tools."

On your local machine where you do have an X-server, start up a terminal, set the ROS_MASTER_URI environment variable to point to the master on computer A, then run rqt_console.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2